# Splash screen with UIActivityIndicatorView loading resources then calling another ViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa

I'm having a hard time trying to do something simple,

I have one viewcontroller that I want to use as a splash screen to the main menu viewcontroller. I can't figure why the modal is not called from the splash.

anybody have idea what is going on?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    UIActivityIndicatorView *indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    indicator.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 180.0, 180.0);
    indicator.center = self.view.center;    
    [self.view addSubview:indicator];
    [indicator bringSubviewToFront:self.view];
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = TRUE;

    //prepare all resources for app

    [indicator startAnimating];

    UIStoryboard*  sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    MainMenuViewController* mainMenu = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"mainMenu"];

    mainMenu.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self presentModalViewController:mainMenu animated:YES];
}
```

if I attach an button pressed event with the same code it works fine:

```
//[btn1 addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressedAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

- (void)buttonPressedAction:(id)sender
{


    UIStoryboard*  sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    MainMenuViewController* mainMenu = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"mainMenu"];

    mainMenu.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self presentModalViewController:mainMenu animated:YES];

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the `viewDidLoad`  to `viewDidAppear` and it worked fine. I don't know why though

Comment: I don't think that you can present another view controller until your view is on screen -- certainly it wouldn't make sense to do so if you want the transition to be animated. The viewDidLoad method is called before the view appears, so it's too early in the process for presenting another view controller.

Comment: thanks for the comment. I agree. It seems so, ambiguous though, what is loaded before viewDidLoad then?

Comment: That method is called after the view controller's view hierarchy is loaded into memory, but before the views appear on screen.